# Task.Whenall(List<Task>) outputs OutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I  have two loops that use SemaphoreSlim and a array of strings "Contents"

a foreachloop:

```
        var allTasks = new List<Task>();
        var throttle = new SemaphoreSlim(10,10);
        foreach (string s in Contents)
        {
            await throttle.WaitAsync();
            allTasks.Add(
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        rootResponse.Add(await POSTAsync(s, siteurl, src, target));
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        throttle.Release();
                    }
                }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

a for loop:

```
        var allTasks = new List<Task>();
        var throttle = new SemaphoreSlim(10,10);
        for(int s=0;s<Contents.Count;s++)
        {
            await throttle.WaitAsync();
            allTasks.Add(
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        rootResponse[s] = await POSTAsync(Contents[s], siteurl, src, target);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        throttle.Release();
                    }
                }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

the first foreach loop runs well, but the for loops Task.WhenAll(allTasks) returns a OutOfRangeException and I want the Contents[] index and List index to match.

Can I fix the for loop? or is there a better approach?

Comment: The problem is the behavior of variable capture of foreach loops and for loops is different. An easy fix is to declare a new variable `int sTemp = s;` and capture that in the anonymous function.

Comment: Is there a web page explaining that difference? I'm not that familiar with foreach loops and I want to learn the detailed reason behind

Comment: I suppose it is complicated by the fact that C# 5 changed the behavior of foreach loop variables to be more natural, but that introduced a breaking change and a conceptual difference between for and foreach loops. There are many questions on the site related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271440/517852). The linked question has links to other articles discussing the issue.

Comment: So I declared a int inside the function but still got the Exception, is there another method where I can add to the List with the same index as the Content[] with the foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would fix your current problems

```
for (int s = 0; s < Contents.Count; s++)
{
   var content = Contents[s];

   allTasks.Add(
      Task.Run(async () =>
                  {
                     await throttle.WaitAsync();
                     try
                     {
                        rootResponse[s] = await POSTAsync(content, siteurl, src, target);
                     }
                     finally
                     {
                        throttle.Release();
                     }
                  }));
}
await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

However this is a fairly messy and nasty piece of code. This looks a bit neater

```
public static async Task DoStuffAsync(Content[] contents, string siteurl, string src, string target)
{
   var throttle = new SemaphoreSlim(10, 10);

   // local method
   async Task<(Content, SomeResponse)> PostAsyncWrapper(Content content)
   {
      await throttle.WaitAsync();
      try
      {
         // return a content and result pair
         return (content, await PostAsync(content, siteurl, src, target));
      }
      finally
      {
         throttle.Release();
      }   
   }

   var results = await Task.WhenAll(contents.Select(PostAsyncWrapper));

   // do stuff with your results pairs here
}
```

There are many other ways you could do this, `PLinq`, `Parallel.For`,`Parallel.ForEach`, Or just tidying up your captures in your loops like above.

However since you have an IO bound work load, and you have `async` methods that run it. The most appropriate solution is the `async` `await` pattern which neither `Parallel.For`,`Parallel.ForEach` cater for optimally.

Another way is [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library which can be found in the [`System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) package.

**Code**

```
public static async Task DoStuffAsync(Content[] contents, string siteurl, string src, string target)
{

   async Task<(Content, SomeResponse)> PostAsyncWrapper(Content content)
   {
      return (content, await PostAsync(content, siteurl, src, target));
   }

   var bufferblock = new BufferBlock<(Content, SomeResponse)>();
   var actionBlock = new TransformBlock<Content, (Content, SomeResponse)>(
      content => PostAsyncWrapper(content),
      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
         {
            EnsureOrdered = false,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100,
            SingleProducerConstrained = true
         });
   actionBlock.LinkTo(bufferblock);

   foreach (var content in contents)
      actionBlock.Post(content);

   actionBlock.Complete();
   await actionBlock.Completion;

   if (bufferblock.TryReceiveAll(out var result))
   {
      // do stuff with your results pairs here   
   }

}
```

Basically this creates a `BufferBlock` And `TransformBlock`, You pump your work load into the `TransformBlock`, it has degrees of parallel in its options, and it pushes them into the `BufferBlock`, you await completion and get your results.

Why Dataflow? because it deals with the `async` `await`, it has `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, it designed for IO bound or CPU Bound workloads, and its extremely simple to use. Additionally, as most data is generally processed in many ways (in a pipeline), you can then use it to pipe and manipulate streams of data in sequence and parallel or in any way way you choose down the line.

Anyway good luck

Comment: Thank you, but I was checking out TPL DataFlow it did not contain EnsureOrdered by default how can I add this?

Comment: @H.Matthew you added the old Dataflow nuget, you need to add the new one System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow nuget and not Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow